# Material Design Ripple/Stay Solid Animation

Tags: android, material-design, rippledrawable

Is there anyway to create an animation that once it ripples then it would stay solid color when the contextual actionbar is activated?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to sucessfully do this by using an ripple animation combined with a statelistdrawable, example below:

Ripple.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/colorPrimary">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask"
          android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/background_selector"/>
 </ripple>
```

Background_Selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: Good. I think its because Ripple Drawable extends LayerDrawable so that this works!